# navigator.geolocation.GetCurrentPosition throws "The last location provider was disabled" error

Tags: android, html, mobile, geolocation, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to create a very basic HTML5 page that grabs the geolocation, but I'm getting an error.

Here's what I have inside my 'script' tags:

```
 function GetGeo() {
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
            alert("Could not find geolocation");
        }
        else {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap, function (error) { alert("error encountered: " + error.message ); });
        }
    }

    function showMap(position) {
        window.alert(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);
    }
```

The page just has a button on it, that calls the GetGeo() function.

What I did is dropped the .html file onto the SDCard of my phone.  Then, I browsed to "content://com.android.htmlfileprovider/sdcard/GetGeo.html" and the page shows up correctly.  When I click the button and execute, I get the following error: "The last location provider was disabled"

I have a couple questions:
1:  Is it wrong to just drop the html file on the SDCard and try to run it there?
2:  Is there something basic that I'm doing wrong that is not letting it get the geolocation from the mobile browser?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I figured this out:  I needed to go into the setting of my mobile browser and check 'Enable Location'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured this out: I needed to go into the setting of my mobile browser and check 'Enable Location'

Comment: I was just going to say that, as I had the same issue myself.

Comment: In case of using a hybrid app (cordova based with nested WebView instead of browser) going to Location Services and enabling ALL options GPS and Wi-fi will fix this issue, i just had this using Cordova 3.X and KitKat all working just fine

Answer (score 3):

It is also important to enable all the location sources from the Android Settings tab. Go to Settings, click on Location and Security. From here, make sure that the following are checked: (1) Use wireless networks, (2) Use GPS satellites, (3) Use sensor aiding.

Also make sure that the following permission is enabled in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```