# phonegap HTML5 geolocation

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I'm trying to get my location coordinates with HTML5 but it gives me error every time .

this is the code I have write to phone gap android project

I used the same code on the documentation of the phone gap geolocation . 
and add the call for the function device-ready () to know if this code is running

and it gives me

```
error 2 : messege 2 :    the last location provider was disabled
```

this is the code  that I'm using to get  my  location on the android device  !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    var watchID = null;

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
    // Update every 3 seconds
    var options = { frequency: 3000 };
    watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                        '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;

//alert("the lang is : "+position.coords.latitude);
document.write("the lang is : "+position.coords.latitude);

    }

// clear the watch that was started earlier
// 
function clearWatch() {
    if (watchID != null) {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
        watchID = null;
    }
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
  alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

</script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p><br>
<button onclick="onDeviceReady();">onDeviceReady()</button>   <br>
<button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>   <br>

    <a href="index2.html"> index 2 </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got this tutorial from here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation !

Hope to suggest what shall I do !!

Comment: This question might help you figure out the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407973/navigator-geolocation-getcurrentposition-throws-the-last-location-provider-was

Comment: it still doesn't working with me , Nothing change  , I enabled the location !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the option enableHighAccuracy to true